For the purposes of notarizing, does the stamp have to be placed on the document?
My teller at the bank just notarized a document. But she didn't not stamp the actual letter. Instead she affixed a document from the National Notary Association titled "Texas Ordinary Certificate of Acknowledgement" which cites Civil Practices & Remedies Code § 121.007. This form has her stamp and all the information.
Do letters notarized no longer get stamped on the letter itself? Is this form attached to the letter the new way notarization works? I seem to recall letters must stamped to be notarized?

Normal practice is to place the notary stamp on the actual document, although not necessarily the same page as the page of the document upon which the notarized signature appears, in the case of a multi-page document. Typically, the language of the notarization block also recites the name of the document being notarized as well as the name of the signer, the capacity in which the signer is signing (i.e. individually or on behalf of an entity as an officer of an entity or as a power of attorney agent for someone), and the date of the notarization.
Best practice when the notarization and signature do not appear on the same page (as is sometimes unavoidable on a document with many signers) is to say "notarization appears on the following page(s)" on the page containing the signature, and to have numbered pages that say page X of Y on each page of the document.
Texas is just slightly weird in this respect.

I've had notaries attach a separate page with the notarization statement and stamp in California on multiple occasions, I don't think Texas is exceptional in this.

@littleadv Texas may not be the only state that does this, but it is the minority practice in the United States. I'm not sure that it is actually disallowed in most states, but the predominant custom in most U.S. states is to not attach a separate notary supplied notarization page. The fact that this is done in both TX and CA suggests that it may be a legacy of the era when these states were part of Mexico.

@ohwilleke so it's better in Texas? ;)

Depending how you count, Texas + Cali cover most of the US :-D re the minority... /s

@EvanCarroll Pretty much nothing is better is Texas. It is a scary place, legally.

New York, Florida (page 7 discusses), North Carolina all have notarial certificates.

@user71659 While they may exist, I've never seen one used in NYS despite practicing law there for about a year.

@howilleke is it fair to see that you've never seen the certificate linked by user71659? I would be surprised if you're saying you've never seen a notarial certificate used in NY.

@GerardAshton Not as a free standing certificate. Every legal document I've ever seen in NYS incorporates a notary clause in substantially that form as part of the document itself, as drafted by a lawyer, rather than as a stand alone notarial certificate. I've drafted hundreds, if not thousands, of documents with notary clauses built into the document itself and seen far more of them. Perhaps a stand alone notarial certificate is usually used in pro se transaction where a notary is making up for the inability of the non-lawyer parties to craft one, and that is the reason.

A common reason I've encountered is that the preprinted clause was written by a lawyer in one state but isn't suitable in the state where the notary is. Pretty common when the signer is on a ski trip to Vermont. What I saw a lot and couldn't use was California certificates.

@GerardAshton A lawyer customizing a document for a specific transaction takes that kind of thing into account. I've done that routinely for years.

Texas lacks an official notary handbook which would summarize the contents of the various relevant Texas laws and administrative code. My answer is based on my general experience as a Vermont notary.
The best practice is to have the signer's signature and all of the notarial certificate on the same page, but this may not be possible for any of several reasons

There isn't enough room on the document's signature page.
The notarial certificate preprinted in the document is wrong for the state the notary is located in, and there isn't enough room to write a replacement certificate on the signature page.

The original poster doesn't say if the letter had any preprinted notarial certificate. If it didn't in nearly every state it would be improper for the notary to merely sign and stamp without adding an appropriate notarial certificate.

No it didn't have a notarial certificate. So getting a letter notarized that doesn't have that certificate printed it on it would necessitate an external certificate being affixed to the document

If there was room and the notary was confident in his/her handwriting, the certificate could have been added on the original document.

For those who didn't know exactly what was being referenced: https://bluenotary.us/what-exactly-is-a-notarial-certificate/

[https://notarypublicunderwriters.com/national-notary-blog/1061-what-is-a-notarial-certificate?srsltid=AfmBOor2iPnfWE-QvLqtbwA0V1YP24PUotkVI0m1Omk98NmBo_2AS_p4](Notary Public Underwriters Blog) has a better summary of what a notarial certificate is. I never recommend BlueNotary documentation.
